# How to bring up symbols in Python ttk.buttons

Tags: button, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I am learning Python3x tkinter on self-study. Practising geometry management widgets, I have designed a calculator that looks somehow like MS Windows Basic Claculator, a snapshot is provided below. The buttons were created with ttk.Button module.  As you see, I could not add the text on backspace arrow <--, +/- and sqrt buttons as exactly they look on MS Windows Calculator. How can I do that? I hope there is a way to add symbols to buttons. I think using bitmap images is not a good option because there will be no harmony amongst the buttons:i.e. buttons with bitmap images will look different than those with text.

Here is a part of the code which needs to be modified to show the symbols correctly:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
backspace = ttk.Button(root, text="<--") 
backspace.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=0, sticky="nw")

plusminus = ttk.Button(root, text="+/-")
plusminus.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nw")

sqroot = ttk.Button(root, text="sqrt")
sqroot.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

Your help is highly appreciated!

[image: Snapshot of my calculator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3 and tkinter work perfectly fine with unicode symboles. So you can just use these sympols directly. For example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
backspace = ttk.Button(root, text="←") 
backspace.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=0, sticky="nw")

plusminus = ttk.Button(root, text="→")
plusminus.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nw")

sqroot = ttk.Button(root, text="√")
sqroot.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

This is just an example. You can find unicode characters/symbols matching more to what you need.